# Searching in XML using another XML data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, xml, select

I have those two tables:

Table1:

```
IDt1    |    XML
1123         xml
1457         xml
```

Table2:

```
ID     |    Name    |    XML
01           A           xml
02           B           xml
```

I want to search in table1 XML and if the data exist, then use the IDt1 and search with it in table2 XML if it exist, then return the ID and Name from table2
here is the XMLs for each table.

Table1 xml:

```
<t>
  <ts>
    <sc>
      <rn>445</rn>
      <am>Name1</am>
    </sc>
    <sc>
      <rn>555/rn>
      <am>Name2</am>
    </sc>
  </ts>
</t>
```

Table2 xml:

```
<t>
  <ts>
    <d>
      <n>01123</n>
    </d>
    <d>
      <n>04344</n>
    </d>
  </ts>
</t>
```

data I want like:

```
ID   |   Name
01        a
```

I was able to retrieve the IDs from table 1 that contain what I'm looking for but then I was not able to use these IDs to search in the other xml.
Here is what I have:

```
SELECT IDt1 as table1IDs
  FROM [Table1]
  WHERE [XML].exist ('/t/ts/sc/am[contains(., "Name1")]') > 0
```

it returns a table of IDs that contain the Name1 now the question how to use the IDs and search with them in the xml of table2 and then return Name and ID of table2
the issue is now I have to use xml.exist [contain table1IDs ] which cannot accept variables

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I appreciate your reduced example and the own effort you show, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several testing I think this does the job

```
DECLARE @searchFor NVARCHAR(max)=N'Name1'
SELECT t2.ID as ID, t2.Name as Name
FROM table1 AS t1 
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.xml.query(N'/t/ts/d/n').value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') = CAST(t1.ID as varchar(max))
WHERE t1.xml.exist(N'/t/ts/sc/am[text()[1]=sql:variable("@searchFor")]')=1 order by ID
```

returns

```
ID   |   Name
01        a
```

Comment: Just as a hint (caused by your comments below my answer): If this works case sensitive or not is depending on the `COLLATION` of your strings... You should not rely on this implicitly

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is quite close, although I would not use `LIKE`... You can try this:

```
DECLARE @dummy1 TABLE(IDt1 INT, xml1 XML);
INSERT INTO @dummy1 VALUES
 (1123,N'<t>
  <ts>
    <sc>
      <rn>445</rn>
      <am>Name1</am>
    </sc>
    <sc>
      <rn>555</rn>
      <am>Name2</am>
    </sc>
  </ts>
</t>')
,(1457,N'<t />'); --you provided only one example...

DECLARE @dummy2 TABLE(ID INT, [Name] VARCHAR(100), [XML] XML);
INSERT INTO @dummy2 VALUES
 (1,'A',N'<t>
  <ts>
    <d>
      <n>01123</n>
    </d>
    <d>
      <n>04344</n>
    </d>
  </ts>
</t>')
,(2,'B',N'<t />'); --you provided only one example...

DECLARE @searchFor NVARCHAR(100)=N'Name1'
SELECT *
FROM @dummy1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN @dummy2 AS t2 ON t2.[XML].exist(N'/t/ts/d/n[text()[1]=sql:column("t1.IDt1")]')=1
WHERE t1.xml1.exist(N'/t/ts/sc/am[text()[1]=sql:variable("@searchFor")]')=1
```

Comment: how to ignore case in `exist(N'/t/ts/d/n[text()[1]=sql:column("t1.IDt1")]'` or to make it upper/lower?

Comment: I tried `N'fn:lower-case/t/ts/d/n[text()[1]=sql:column("t1.IDt1")]'` return 0, so I'm not sure if this answer is correct

Comment: @FrankoT, do I get this correctly: You want to find "Name1" even with "name1" or "nAmE1"? Cannot test it at the moment, but using an `XQuery`-function would need paranthesis like `lower-case(SomeXPathSingleton)`. I'd assume you'd put this *within* the predicat like `.../am[lower-case(text())=lower-case(sql:variable(blah))]`. Hth

Comment: no I meant whne I do the t1.IDt1 because my ID is actually a guid. I was able to make it work doing this after inner join, `t2 ON t2.[XML].query(N'/t/ts/d/n').value('.', 'varchar(max)') = CAST(t1.IDt1 as varchar(36))` that made it to work, but yet it still misses some rows are not returned as my solution does.

Comment: Figured it out, mine doing contain instead of exact. yours search exactly form Name1. Thanks Shnugo

Comment: I think you should re-tag your question as it uses `sql-server` obviously.